# How to conditionally open a new window/tab from an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code that will open a new tab/window and display the contents of a file based on a user clicking a button in a grid.

```
$(myButton).attr('href', '/MyController/GetDoc?Field1=' + dataItem.data1 + '&Field2=' + dataItem.data2);    
$(myButton).attr('target', '_blank');
```

In the controller I return

```
return new FileContentResult(Convert.FromBase64String(myDoc), "application/pdf");
```

Everything works fine if I have a document.

How can I prevent the event from occurring if the controller method errors out or no document was found?

UPDATE:

```
$(function () {

    $(".myButtonClass").each(function () {
        var button = $(this);
        var docUrl = '';

        button.attr('target', '_blank');
        checkDocumentUrl(button, docUrl);
    });

});
```

In my button click method:

```
var myButton = $(e.currentTarget).closest(".myButtonClass");
$(myButton).attr('href', '/MyContoller/GetDoc?Field1=' + dataItem.data1+ '&Field2=' + dataItem.data2);
```

Comment: You can't. Ypur literally opening a page in a new tab. The error happens after your code has ran.

Comment: Why don't you just return a friendly error message from your server side

Answer (score 0):

*Before* the button is clicked, request the document from the server. If that fails, the document does not exist, and you can disable the button through JavaScript.

Your controller should check if the document exists, and return `HTTP 404` if it does not.

```js
//Example data only. Each button presumably has its own data.
var dataItem = {
  data1: 'foo',
  data2: 'bar'
};

$(document).ready(function() {

  //Check the url for each button
  $('.myButton').each(function() {
    var button = $(this);

    var docUrl = '/MyController/GetDoc?Field1=' + dataItem.data1 + '&Field2=' + dataItem.data2;

    button.attr('href', docUrl);
    button.attr('target', '_blank');

    checkDocumentUrl(button, docUrl);
  });

  function checkDocumentUrl(button, docUrl) {
    //Make a request for the document
    $.ajax({
      method: 'HEAD',
      url: docUrl,
      error: function() {
        //If request fails, document does not exist
        handleInvalidDocument(button, docUrl);
      }
    });
  }

  function handleInvalidDocument(button, docUrl) {
    button.on('click', function(e) {
      //Prevent the link from opening a new tab
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('Sorry, no document available at ' + docUrl);
    });
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="myButton">My Button</a>
```

Comment: I like this approach but can't get it to work.  I can't set the docUrl in the document.ready since those values will be set by each row in my grid.

Comment: @JDS, you're setting the `href` attribute programmatically via jQuery, correct? When do you set the `href` attribute? Where is `dataItem` defined?